# Unable to build using Ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

I'm trying to build an OCaml project using ocaml build command which looks similar to

> ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind test.byte

Following error is observed.

Error: Unbound value String.lowercase_ascii. 
I have install Clang and i am using OCaml 4.07.0

Answer (score 1):

The function `String.lowercase_ascii` was introduced in OCaml 4.03. You should check that you are really using OCaml 4.07 and not an earlier version.

Comment: In particular, `ocamlfind ocamlc -v` will return the OCaml version used through `ocamlfind`.